# Firebase user changes email or phone number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Building an Android app with a Firebase backend the next step in development is to configure the API for buying and selling goods inside the app. The API will use the phone number and naturally, it will keep an audit trail of transactions. Firebase SMS authentication is a good match for the app.

However, this app is not intended for the US. Users may want to change carriers and that could mean changing phone numbers. What do we do if the user changes their phone number? A similar issue could come up if the model were email and the user were changing their email account (e.g. changing the app's email login account from gmail.com to facebook.com).

It looks like this would be a manual process where the user can work with our admin team to create the new account, validate it with an SMS and then find and replace the old UUID with the new UUID. When the refs are updated with the new user key, all the data will move into the new account.

Is there a better way? Has anybody got a 'user move' script that might be adapted to our app?

Any insight from the Firebase team is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication has methods to change the [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential)) and [email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address) on an existing account. These don't change the UID of the user, so won't require you to update the database.

Comment: The solution requires the user to login using the original in order to change it. That should do the trick. Thanks very much. Of course, I have to ask... is there anything to do if the original number/phone is lost?

Comment: They'll have to authenticate in some way in order to update their credentials, otherwise anyone could change the credentials on any user account.

Comment: Can a user with access to the data through the console call the "updatePhoneNumber" method or some API to make the change?  
Where our app is going people changing phone companies are changing numbers. A lost phone and new sim from the same company should be good for recovery. Changing numbers without access to the original number is our worst case - a corner case. The user with the lost number has the context to prove who they are to the admin team. That user can create a new account to set up the new number and work with the team to run a console script for the one-off process.

Comment: There is no functionality to update those properties in the Firebase console, but you can use the Admin SDK to [update anything in the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Comment: U R the best! Thank you, Frank

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-authenticate the current user using

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential("user@gmail.com", "userPassword");
user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(
    //Code to handle successful completion of authentication.
);
```

You did the above re-authentication to check whether correct user is trying to change the email address.

After doing the above authentication, if the `onComplete` in `addOnCompleteListener` is successful, then you have to update the current email using the method below.

```
user.updateEmail("newEmail@example.com").addOnCompleteListener();
```

Again, check whether the updating email was successful in `onComplete(){}` and take the appropriate actions.